# How to use flexbox to show most recent posts first?

Tags: css, jekyll, flexbox

I am using Jekyll to set up a website, and I am using a flexbox model where viewers can click on a post and it will take them to the article page. The problem is that my grid is set up to show 3 posts per row, then wrap. By default, the first published post is the first post you see, and the newest posts end up at the end, so I am trying to use flexbox to reverse this.

If I have only 7 posts on the site, the last post will be on a line of its own, with two empty spaces, so if I use 'wrap-reverse', that post will be the only post on the top row, which isn't what I want. I would like for my posts to show up as: [7,6,5 - 4,3,2 - 1] from left to right, instead of the defaulted [1,2,3 - 4,5,6 - 7], where 7 is the newest article and 1 is the oldest.

I am looking for a possible method to arrange my posts in a clean fashion, so that as I upload new posts, they automatically publish in the top left of the grid layout. Sorry if this may sound confusing. If you have any questions that will help to understand what I am talking about please feel free to ask.

Here is some code from codepen that illustrates what I have. 
http://codepen.io/pen/?editors=110

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='post'>1 (oldest post)</div>
    <div class='post'>2</div>
    <div class='post'>3</div>
    <div class='post'>4</div>
    <div class='post'>5</div>
    <div class='post'>6</div>
    <div class='post'>7 (newest post)</div>
  </div>
</body>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post {
  height: 170px;
  width: 220px;
  background: black;
  color: orange;
  margin: 10px; 
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I basically want 7 to replace 1, 6 to replace 2, 5 to replace 3, etc. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Flex-direction: row/column-reverse

Comment: Unfortunately, `flexbox` doesn't really offer the kind of "magic bullet" you are looking for. The real solution would be to adjust Jekyll to publish in most recent order.

Comment: Has anyone looked at my answer? Is it wrong?

Comment: Wrong, no...but the OP hasn't responded yet.

Comment: Perhaps a [**Jekyll Plugin**](https://github.com/kylepaulsen/Jekyll-Sort)?

Comment: David gave a great fix below that is build right into Jekyll that works with flex grids. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse an array with Jekyll you just can *reverse* this array order, which, by default, is sorted by date :

```
<div class="container">
{% for post in site.posts reversed %}
  <div class='post'>{{post.title}}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: There just *had* to be a setting in Jekyll for this. +1

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks David

Answer (score 2):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYYqjK

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Use `row-reverse`. This will change the direction of the row to rtl. Without `justify-content` this would seems to float the elements right. Fix that by adding `justify-content`.

However, the best approach would be to change your HTML output all together. If you're working with Wordpress or any other CMS this ought to be quite simple.

---

As Paulie_D notes, this works only when there's no wrap. You can partially solve this by adding `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` but [that will look a bit strange](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaaJbv).

Comment: Doesn't work...7 is not first although you were close.

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean? I added a screenshot.

Comment: Not when wrapping take place...check it out.

Comment: @Paulie_D You're right. I added an update. However, I'm not sure how to get rid of the annoying whitespace at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would definitely need the grid to wrap. It David found a fix build right into Jekyll!

Answer (score 1):

So you want reverse order? Look here: http://codepen.io/01/pen/eppowq

**EDIT**

Let me clarify, assigning order in itself is a simple reliable solution, I'm only suggesting JavaScript to expand upon the topic.

You can use jQuery or JavaScript to manipulate the `order` property easily.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='post' style="order:7">1 (oldest post)</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:6">2</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:5">3</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:4">4</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:3">5</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:2">6</div>
    <div class='post' style="order:1">7 (newest post)</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I made a demo that randomly reorders flex items: http://codepen.io/01/pen/BNbpLN

You could modify the code to your own design.

Comment: I would be highly against this since it is achievable with css and if using JavaScript it should reverse the order itself.

Comment: @Akxe I suggest you submit a solution with CSS only then, I would like to see it. Btw, I suggested this because the OP doesn't want `wrap-reverse`. The solution I set before him is CSS it's `order`.

Comment: @zer00ne this definitely does work, but it would require too much extra code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: True the markup would be cumbersome if you plan to have more than 10 posts displayed at a time.